# Check if NFC tag is near

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to force android to check if an NFC tag is near? I'm only able to read the tag when android detects it, I would like to force it to check if a tag is near at a specific moment

Comment: In order to check if a tag is near, it has to detect that tag... This is not really logical.

Comment: I need to check if an nfc tag is sticked at the back of the phone, it's a clients requisite

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is in general not possible. However if you can live with a dirty hack the following will work (thanks to unspecified behaviour):

First disable the reader-mode of all supported tag types. This brings the NFC subsystem into a clean state, e.g. it makes sure that the NFC controller will have no connection to the tag.

Once done restore the reader-mode again. If a tag is present at that moment you will get the usual discovery action as an intent. It may take a second or two though.

Control of the reader-mode is possible using `NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode` and `NfcAdapter.disableReaderMode`

Comment: The idea is OK, but it only works with API 19... Is it any possibility with older android versions?

Comment: @Mikel If you have system privileges you could enable and disable the entire NFC subsystem in the same way as the settings app does it.

Comment: @Mikel Well, in this case you can unfortunately not implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and it works ! It will continuously check if the NFC tag is near to the phone or not.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    readFromIntent(intent);
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        checkNFCStatus();
        handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }

    }, 1000);

    }
}

public void checkNFCStatus(){
    try {
        if(myTag != null) {
            Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(myTag);
            ndefTag.connect();
            if (ndefTag.isConnected()) {
                Log.d("network", "NFC connected");
            } else {
                Log.d("network", "NFC disconnected");
            }
            ndefTag.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("network", "NFC disconnected");
    }
}

//If the connection is not closed, an exception will be thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a bit of a hack for this that works (for me, at least!)

First, when you initially detect the tag via the `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`, get the tag as a field in your class and start a timer (this is in C#/Xamarin but the same should apply for Java):

```
_tag = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;

ReaderTimer = new Timer(2000);
ReaderTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
ReaderTimer.Start();
```

Now, every 2 seconds this will fire. It will attempt to reconnect to the tag. If it can't the tag is gone.:

```
    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tag == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.Get(_tag);

        if (ndef == null)
        {
            // NDEF is not supported by this Tag.
            return;
        }

        if (!ndef.IsConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                ndef.Close();
                ndef.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // could not reconnect
                // implies tag is not in proximity

                //do whatever needs to be done when NFC is disconnected

                ReaderTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tested this with API 14.

Unfortunately when the screen is turned off `ndef.Connect()` fails, so that is registered as a disconnect.

Comment: Right, storing the tag handle and trying to connect at a later time should work. However, there may be some issues with this: (1) NFC is intended for short interactions. Consequently, the tag handle may not be valid forever (particularly when the physical connection with the tag dropped for a moment in between two connection retries). (2) Be aware that for some tag technologies (or on some Android versions???) `connect()` does not necessarily cause an I/O operation on the tag and therefore may succeed even if the connection to the tag was lost (you could use `getNdefMessage()`in to force I/O).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll take that into consideration.