# Is it possible to programatically detect the proximity of a NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc

When my phone is beside a NFC tag and I turn on the screen the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` fires. Is it possible to trigger this  e.g. on a button click or on a timer? If so, how?

To elaborate a little, I want my phone to exhibit certain behaviours only when in the proximity of the NFC tag. I need to be able to detect when this proximity is lost to turn off the behaviours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if NFC tag is near](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017813/check-if-nfc-tag-is-near)

Comment: This answer outlines how to do so:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27060920/181771